# Is infinity included in SQL standard?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sqldatatypes

In postgres, date/time types have a special value infinity or -infinity. Are those standard SQL values, or is this a postgres addition?

Answer (score 5):

It is a PostgreSQL addition.

The standard time range starts at 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000 and ends at 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999 (and time zones add to the fun of making that definition work).

There was a (US) Air Force contract AF251 in the late 1980s that required a 'doomsday' as a sort of temporal infinity.  I'm not sure which DBMS got the contract, and whether the systems retained that concept generally.  However, I think most don't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no concept of infinity in SQL. Generally if the result of an operation is higher than the storage of particular data type it will throw the exception or arithimetic overflow. Datetime doesnt have any uppler lower limit and hence the time can be percieved as ranging from -Infinity to +Infinity.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the max value for a smalldatetime in SqlServer is 2079-06-06